# Cypher query equivalent for neo4j-import

Tags: import, neo4j, cypher

I'm trying to create a about 27 millions relationships along with 15 million nodes, initially I was using Cypher, but it was taking a lot of time, so I switched neo4j-import tool utility.

I have confusion whether the result of cypher query is same as that of neo4j-import.

My Cypher query was:

```
load csv from "file://dataframe6.txt" as line fieldterminator" "
MERGE (A :concept{name:line[0]})
WITH line, A
MERGE (B :concept{name:line[1]})
WITH B,A
MERGE (A)-[:test]->(B);
```

Content in dataframe6 :

```
C0000005,C0036775,RB_
C0000039,C0000039,SY_sort_version_of
C0000039,C0000039,SY_entry_version_of
C0000039,C0000039,SY_permuted_term_of
C0000039,C0001555,AQ_
C0000039,C0001688,AQ_
```

My neo4j-import script:

```
neo4j-import --into graph.db --nodes:concept "nheader,MRREL-nodes" --relationships "rheader,MRREL-relations"  --skip-duplicate-node true
```

rheader : :START_ID,:END_ID,:TYPE

nheader : :ID,name

MRREL-nodes :

```
C0000005,C0000005
C0000039,C0000039
C0000052,C0000052
C0036775,C0036775
C0001555,C0001555
```

MRREL-relations

```
C0000005,C0036775,RB_
C0000039,C0000039,SY_sort_version_of
C0000039,C0000039,SY_entry_version_of
C0000039,C0000039,SY_permuted_term_of
C0000039,C0001555,AQ_
C0000039,C0001688,AQ_
```

Somehow I don't see same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EDITED]

1. If you want your relationships to have dynamically assigned types, then you need to change your Cypher code to make use of `line[2]` to specify the relationship type (e.g., via the APOC procedure [apoc.create.relationship](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_creating_data)). It is currently always using `test` as the type.
2. If, instead, you actually wanted all the relationships imported by `neo4j-import` to have the same `test` type, then you need to use the [right syntax](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tutorial/import-tool/#import-tool-same-relationship-type-for-every-relationship-example).

   Try removing ",:TYPE" from `rheader`, and use this import command line ( `--relationships` has been changed to `--relationships:test`):

   ```
   neo4j-import --into graph.db --nodes:concept "nheader,MRREL-nodes" --relationships:test "rheader,MRREL-relations"  --skip-duplicate-node true
   ```

Comment: yeah , I know, but I'm really interested in creating nodes having same label and property